# Pyramid callback after response is sent and connection closed

Tags: python, heroku, callback, wsgi, pyramid

I need a callback in Pyramid that would be executed after the response was sent and connection to the client closed.

I'm aware of [finished callbacks](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/master/narr/hooks.html#using-finished-callbacks). This is however not what I want. Finished callbacks are evaluated right before the connection is closed (as far as I can tell).

Any clues? I need that for sending emails without creating a few second delay. Typically I should use something like Celery, I guess. I can't however afford a background worker on Heroku.

Comment: I'd probably just use pyramid_mailer in queued mode.

Comment: @ChrisMcDonough, When you make admin panel for Pyramid? I tired make new one on every project. ))

Comment: Me?  Dunno.  There are a number of them now.  But this isn't an appropriate place to talk about it.

Answer (score 2):

My understanding is that a WSGI application is basically a Python function which recieves a set of arguments and *returns* an blob of text which represents an HTTP respose. That blob may be passed to some filters in WSGI pipeline, which also are just functions, after which the webserver sends the response to the client and closes the connection. From the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Server_Gateway_Interface):

```
def application(environ, start_response):
    start_response('200 OK', [('Content-Type', 'text/plain')])
    yield 'Hello World\n'
```

As Pyramid is a WSGI application, you can see that things like connection closing are likely to happen outside of its area of influence.

In your situation, if you can't/don't want to use existing solutions (pyramid_mailer in queued mode, as suggested by Chris McDonough), I would look at something like having a background [thread](http://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#thread-objects) which reads data every few seconds from a [queue](http://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html#module-Queue) and sends emails. Then your view code just puts data in the queue and happily returns, while the working thread sends emails.

Comment: I think that as well, I ended up sending an email in a separate thread. Obviously threads in Python aren't very multi-threaded because of the GIL, but in this case that's actually okay.

Comment: Should I add, the thread is actually started at the end of the request that produces an email and exits once it's done sending that particular email. Not a perfect solution, but suffices for now.

Comment: great and correct answer, BTW, a wsgi app can also return an iterator, but most of the time, it is just a blob of text as you said.